# Is there equivalent C# function for "mysqli_fetch_array"?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, visual-studio, winforms

So I want to manually convert the PHP function to C# Windows Form but I don't know the equivalent function mysqli_fetch_array in C# and how to do array PHP in C#?

I've googling but there is no correct solution.

This is in C# Windows Form

```
openConnection();
                    string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM data_pegawai WHERE is_deleted=0 AND username='" + user + "'";
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (valuesList = reader.Read())
                    {
                        id = reader.GetInt32("id_peg");
                    }
                    closeConnection();

                    kembali = bayar - subtotal;
                    lblKembali.Text = kembali.ToString();

                    string insertQuery1 = "UPDATE data_transaksi SET status_pengerjaan='Lunas',potongan_harga='" + diskonrupiah.ToString() + "',subtotal='" + txtSubtotal.Text + "' WHERE id_transaksi =" + int.Parse(txtID_T.Text);
                    string insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO pegawai_onduty VALUES(NULL, '" + id + "','" + txtID_T.Text + "')";

                    openConnection();
                    string selectQuery1 = "SELECT dsp.id_spareparts, dtsp.JUMLAH_SPAREPART from data_transaksi dt LEFT JOIN detail_transaksi_sparepart dtsp ON dt.id_transaksi=dtsp.id_transaksi LEFT JOIN spareparts_motor sm ON dtsp.ID_SPAREPARTMOTOR=sm.ID_SPAREPARTMOTOR LEFT JOIN data_spareparts dsp ON sm.id_spareparts=dsp.id_spareparts where dtsp.id_transaksi =" + int.Parse(txtID_T.Text);
                    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                        int getData = "SELECT jumlah_stok FROM data_spareparts dsp WHERE id_spareparts='$jml[0]'";
                    }
                    closeConnection();


                    runQuery(insertQuery1);
                    runQuery(insertQuery2);
                    loadTransaksi();
```

And this is PHP code that I trying to convert to

```
while($jml=mysqli_fetch_array($dataJumlah))
            {
                $getData    = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT jumlah_stok FROM data_spareparts dsp WHERE id_spareparts='$jml[0]' ") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
                $dataSP   = mysqli_fetch_array($getData);
                $idSpareparts = $dataSP[0];
                $jmlStok      = (int) $dataSP[0];
                $jmlJual      = (int) $jml[1];
                $sisaStok     =  $jmlStok-$jmlJual;
                $updateStok   = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE data_spareparts SET jumlah_stok=$sisaStok WHERE id_spareparts='$jml[0]'") or die (mysqli_error($conn));

            }
```

So I want to do "while($jml=mysqli_fetch_array($dataJumlah))" in C# and the rest of it. But how?

Comment: You have the DataReader there, just use it

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered.
Below is the answer

```
subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtSubtotal.Text);
                bayar = Convert.ToDouble(txtBayar.Text);
                if (bayar < subtotal)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nominal yang dibayarkan lebih kecil dari Subtotal!");
                }
                else
                {
                    openConnection();
                    string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM data_pegawai WHERE is_deleted=0 AND username='" + user + "'";
                    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                        id = reader1.GetInt32("id_peg");
                    }
                    closeConnection();

                    kembali = bayar - subtotal;
                    lblKembali.Text = kembali.ToString();

                    string insertQuery1 = "UPDATE data_transaksi SET status_pengerjaan='Lunas',potongan_harga='" + diskonrupiah.ToString() + "',subtotal='" + txtSubtotal.Text + "' WHERE id_transaksi =" + int.Parse(txtID_T.Text);
                    string insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO pegawai_onduty VALUES(NULL, '" + id + "','" + txtID_T.Text + "')";

                    openConnection();
                    string selectQuery1 = "SELECT dsp.id_spareparts, dtsp.JUMLAH_SPAREPART from data_transaksi dt LEFT JOIN detail_transaksi_sparepart dtsp ON dt.id_transaksi=dtsp.id_transaksi LEFT JOIN spareparts_motor sm ON dtsp.ID_SPAREPARTMOTOR=sm.ID_SPAREPARTMOTOR LEFT JOIN data_spareparts dsp ON sm.id_spareparts=dsp.id_spareparts where dtsp.id_transaksi =" + int.Parse(txtID_T.Text);
                    MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery1, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader2.Read())
                    {
                        idSparepart = reader2.GetString(0);
                        jmlJual = reader2.GetInt32(1);

                    }
                    closeConnection();

                    openConnection();
                    string getData = "SELECT jumlah_stok FROM data_spareparts dsp WHERE id_spareparts='" + idSparepart + "'";
                    MySqlCommand command3 = new MySqlCommand(getData, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader3.Read())
                    {
                        jmlStok = reader3.GetInt32(0);
                    }
                    closeConnection();

                    sisastok = jmlStok - jmlJual;

                    string updateStok = "UPDATE data_spareparts SET jumlah_stok = '" + sisastok + "' WHERE id_spareparts ='" + idSparepart + "'";
                    try
                    {
                        openConnection();
                        MySqlCommand command4 = new MySqlCommand(updateStok, conn);
                        if (command4.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Data tidak berhasil disimpan!");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        closeConnection();
                    }

                    runQuery(insertQuery1);
                    runQuery(insertQuery2);
                    loadTransaksi();
                }
```